# Can't open terminal tabs with VSCode

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I have installed [terminal tabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.terminal-tabs) for VSCode and modified the `keybindings.json` as instructed:

[image]

However pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> does not open a new terminal. How can I open a new terminal tab from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [command needs to skip the shell, so it can go to the terminal itself](https://github.com/Tyriar/vscode-terminal-tabs/issues/13#event-1161581221). Open **Preferences** -> **Settings** and modify `commandsToSkipShell`:

```
"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
  (existing settings)
  "terminalTabs.createTerminal"
]
```